# Payment with Stripe on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have followwed many tutorials from the internet to find out how to payment with card credit. All i go so far is:
My payment form:

```
<%= form_for(@payment, :html => {:id => 'payment-form'}) do |f| %>
            <div class="form-group">
                <%= f.label :name %>
                <%= f.text_field :name, :class => 'form-control' %>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <%= f.label :phone %>
                <%= f.text_field :phone, :class => 'form-control' %>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <%= f.label :address %>
                <%= f.text_area :address, :class => 'form-control' %>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <%= f.label 'Payment Type' %>
                <%= f.select :pay_type, Payment.pay_types.keys, {},:class => 'form-control' %>
            </div>
             <div class="form-group">
                <label>Card Number</label>
                <input type="text" size="20" autocomplete="off" data-stripe="number" id="number" class="credit-number form-control" placeholder = "**** **** **** ****" value = "4242424242424242" pattern="[\d ]*" />
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Security Code/CVC</label>
                <input type="text" size="4" autocomplete="off" data-stripe="cvc" id="cvc" class="credit-scurity form-control" placeholder="***" value = "123" pattern="\d*" />
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Expiration (MM/YYYY)</label>
                <input type="text" size="2" data-stripe="exp_month" id="exp-month" class="card-expiry-month form-control" placeholder="MM" pattern="\d*" />
                <span> / </span>
                <input type="text" size="4" data-stripe="exp_year" id="exp-year" class="card-expiry-year form-control" placeholder="YYYY" pattern="\d*" />
            </div>
            <div class="actions">
                <%= f.submit 'Place order', :class => 'btn btn-primary btn-payment' %>
            </div>
         </div>
        <% end %>
```

And the script in this form:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
  var show_error, stripeResponseHandler;
  $("#payment-form").submit(function (event) {
    var $form;
    $form = $(this);
    $form.find("input[type=submit]").prop("disabled", true);
    Stripe.card.createToken($form, stripeResponseHandler);
    return false;
  });
  stripeResponseHandler = function (status, response) {
    var $form, token;
    $form = $("#payment-form");
    if (response.error) {
      show_error(response.error.message);
      $form.find("input[type=submit]").prop("disabled", false);
    } else {
      token = response.id;
      $form.append($('<input type="hidden" name="stripeToken" />').val(token));
      $("[data-stripe=number]").remove();
      $("[data-stripe=cvv]").remove();
      $("[data-stripe=exp-year]").remove();
      $("[data-stripe=exp-month]").remove();
      $form.get(0).submit();
    }
    return false;
  };

  show_error = function (message) {
    $("#flash-messages").html('<div class="alert alert-warning"><a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</a><div id="flash_alert">' + message + '</div></div>');
    $('.alert').delay(5000).fadeOut(3000);
    return false;
  };
});
```

payments.controller:

```
def create
    @payment = Payment.new(payment_params)
    Stripe.api_key = "sk_test_Hm0ywtd94a4e27SHOfzVJLpZ"
    @cart = current_cart
     @amount = @cart.total_price.to_i * 100

      token = params[:stripeToken]
      debugger
      # Create a Customer
      customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
        :description => params[:email], 
        :card => token
      )


  charge = Stripe::Charge.create(

    :customer    => customer.id,
    :amount => @amount, # amount in cents, again
    :currency => 'usd',
    :card => token,
    :description => params[:email]
  )
    if @payment.save
        @payment.add_line_items_from_cart(current_cart)
        Cart.destroy(session[:cart_id])
        session[:cart_id] = nil
        redirect_to root_path
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end
```

Now i get the error: "Cannot charge a customer that has no active card"
I'm try debugging and the problem is:

```
token = params[:stripeToken]
```

the params[:stripeToken] is nil then token is nil too.
Please help me

Answer (score 0):

George, if params[:stripeToken] is nil it's a good bet it's never being appended to the form in the first place. Look at your javascript:

```
 if (response.error) {
  show_error(response.error.message);
  $form.find("input[type=submit]").prop("disabled", false);
} else {
  token = response.id;
  $form.append($('<input type="hidden" name="stripeToken" />').val(token));
```

My best guess is you're getting an error which prevents your $form.append code from happening.

To test my theory you should inspect the form in question for errors.
https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/